# How to copy a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy data from a closed Excel file to the workbook I am currently in. I would like to browse for the file and then have the macro do the rest.

I am getting an error in the target workbook that says

> "Application-defined or object defined error."

Below is what I have so far. Target is the workbook I am opening and y is the current one, or should be at least!

```
Option Explicit
Sub getfilename()

Dim myFilePath As String
Dim target As Workbook, y As Workbook

myFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename()

'copying
Set target = Workbooks.Open(myFilePath)

target.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("R9C2:R20C2").Copy

'pasting
Set y = ActiveWorkbook

y.Sheets("Adjustment").Cells("R57C4").PasteSpecial

'close
target.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using R1C1 notation to get the range? Because that's the source of your problem, and the solution will depend on why you're using that notation.

Comment: No particular reason, just have always used R1C1

Comment: Use `y.Sheets("Adjustment").Cells(57, 4).PasteSpecial`.

Comment: When you `.Open` a workbook, typically it becomes the `ActiveWorkbook`. `Set y = ActiveWorkbook` **before** you open the source workbook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RANGE object expects A1 notation rather than R1C1 notation. The CELLS object can use row number and column number (though you don't need the R..C.. structure there, either.

```
Sub getfilename()

Dim myFilePath As String
Dim target As Workbook, y As Workbook

myFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename()

Set y = ActiveWorkbook

'copying
Set target = Workbooks.Open(myFilePath)

'Here we're using the A1 notation
target.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2","B9").Copy

'Here we're using the Row & Column numbers notation
y.Sheets("Adjustment").Cells(57, 4).PasteSpecial

'close
target.Close

End Sub
```

In addition, you don't actually need to use the Copy and PasteSpecial methods to duplicate values. It's not too big a deal in a small macro like this, but in a larger process you'd find it more efficient to duplicate the values directly using something like:
    target.Range("A1","A10").value = source.Range("A1","A10").value

Comment: Another good reason not to use Copy / PasteSpecial is the fact that it goes via the clipboard, and if the user is doing anything while the macro is running in the background, and the user also copy / pastes something, the results can be disastrous.  +1 for recommending against its use!